# Multiple instances of query_posts

Tags: query-posts

I need to have 8 of these on a single page.
Each post list  will be in its own numbered switch tab.

Is there a better, more efficient way of doing it?

```
<div id="tab1">
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <?php
            // The Query
            query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'CV', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

            // The Loop
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <?php endwhile;

            // Reset Query
            wp_reset_query();            
        ?>
    </ul>
</div><!-- / .content -->
</div><!-- / #tab1 -->
```

EDITED TO ADD FINAL CODE:

```
<?php
// getting only children of category ID 16
$categories = get_categories('child_of=16');
// do not need to check for empty categories
{
?>

<ul class="tabs">
<?php foreach ($categories as $c ) { ?>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab<?php echo $c->term_id; ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo-<?php echo $c->slug; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $c->name; ?>" />
      </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul> <!-- / .tabs -->

<?php } ?>

<?php { foreach ($categories as $c ) { ?>
<div id="tab<?php echo $c->term_id; ?>">
<a href="#" class="left-button"><img src="prev.png" alt="Prev" /></a>
<div class="content">
    <?php
    $q = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => $c->term_id ) );
    if ( $q->have_posts() ) : ?> <ul class="tabs-content"> <?php while( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();
    ?>
    <li>
      <h3>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?></a>
      </h3>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?> </ul> <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div><!-- / .content -->
<a href="#" class="right-button"><img src="next.png" alt="Next" /></a>
</div><!-- / #tab<?php echo $c->term_id; ?> -->
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: What differ one tab from another, the category?

Comment: Yes, all categories are different. And each tab header has a different image (logo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 8 categories, you need 8 queries. To improve your code use `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts`:

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories();
if ( ! empty($categories) ) {
?>
<ul class="tabs">
<?php foreach ($categories as $c ) { ?>
<li>
  <a href="#tab<?php echo $c->term_id; ?>">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo-<?php echo $c->slug; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $c->name; ?>" />
  </a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul> <!-- / .tabs -->
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( ! empty($categories) ) { foreach ($categories as $c ) { ?>
<div id="tab<?php echo $c->term_id; ?>">
<a href="#" class="left-button"><img src="prev.png" alt="Prev" /></a>
<div class="content">
<?php
$q = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => $c->term_id ) );
if ( $q->have_posts() ) : ?> <ul> <?php while( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();
?>
<li>
  <h3>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
  <?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </h3>
  <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?> </ul> <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div><!-- / .content -->
<a href="#" class="right-button"><img src="next.png" alt="Next" /></a>
</div><!-- / #tab<?php echo $c->term_id; ?> -->
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Two things: 1) I think you missed <li>'s in there; 2) where would I assign category name or ID this way? Sorry, don't get it.

Comment: `$category->term_id` is the id, `$category->name` is the name. Now I'm updating code for the `<li>`. But in your code there is no `<li>`

Comment: My mistake, I was deleting some code before sharing and li's were lost in the process.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there. It doesn't work for me in this particular situation but useful anyway, thank you. I need to have more control over the look and tab ID's. ---- 
   Would 8 instances of query_posts be very bad, or acceptable?

Comment: Consider that query_posts call WP_Query so you are the same thing, for that I don't understand what the matter. You can do with this code do whatever (and much more) you should do with 8 query_posts... What are you using for tab, bootstrap? jquery ui? or something else?

Comment: For the tabs, I'm using jQuery (non-UI). ---- Like I mentioned, each tab has a logo image. How would you include a unique image for each one? Here's the entire code if you'd like to see: http://jsfiddle.net/phantasmix/masnb/

Comment: The logos must be named in the form `logo-{$category-slug}.png`.  The code edited now should works. I think you have to adjust `<img src="prev.png" alt="Prev" />` and `<img src="next.png" alt="Next" /></a>` with the right url of your images. After that, in your fiddle, I can see from jquery that somewhere should be a `#button-bottom` but in the html there isn't.

Comment: Thanks for further looking into it. Very strange: it outputs the structure for the tabs perfectly, but the content isn't broken down into separate "slides". Tabs are ok. But all content is shown on one "slide" as divs, one on top of another. --- I also realized that I need post meta, arghhh!! I need to output 2 custom fields near the_content

Comment: Found it -- <a href="#<?php echo $c->term_id; ?>"> this needs "tab" like this: <a href="#tab<?php echo $c->term_id; ?>">. Works great!

Comment: Meta fields work as-is! Thank you again for your code.

Comment: You are welcome. I've edited the for completeness.